# Apache Camel file input delete directory

Tags: apache, directory, parent

a camel route reads a file. Actually two and combining them via aggregation. And these are serveral routes in one routebuilder. But the problem can tracked down to one route.

I scan for file like "/foo/bar/bar.xml". 
After the route or at its end I want to delete the parent directory "/foo/bar", too. Because it is created just for bar.xml and bar_1.xml ...

I created a processor to do this. But even in the last route the directory is still not empty. After the route the directory is empty.

How can I do this? There are options for file deleting. But I cannot delete its parent dir.

The route is called from activiti it that helps.

Thanks for input
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

what you need is onCompletion construct. Something like this:

```
 <route>
        <from uri="direct:fileInput"/>
        <onCompletion>
            <!--bean with the logic to delete the directory-->
            <bean ref="dirDeletionBean" method="deleteDirectory">
        </onCompletion>
        <process ref="myProcessor"/>
        <to uri="rabbitmq...."/>
    </route>
```

You can read more about it [here](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html)